# Skype messages sent when I was offline not delivered immediately

Tags: skype

I'm using Skype 4.2 on Ubuntu 13.04. If a contact sends me a message when I'm offline, I don't receive it the moment I'm back online. I only get them like 10-20 hours later (apparently, when this contact becomes online as well). On Windows it wasn't like that. Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: I think the message is delivered once the contact who sent it is online again, and I think it was always like that. I sometimes get messages with several days of delay (say, over weekend) because the contact is away for that period. I think there is no difference on Windows in that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype is p2p, so both uses have to be online for a message to be shared. Read more [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/delay-in-receiving-chat-messages/m-p/24732/highlight/true#M3005). The operating system doesn't really matter (note that the forum link is for windows)

Answer (score 1):

Just to update, the behaviour has changed now. Skype has introduced a cloud service, which will store offline messages in case both parties have a cloud-enabled client. Unfortunately I expect that any Linux client is not cloud-enabled right now. See also here: [Will my instant message be delivered if the recipient is not signed in to Skype?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10646/will-my-instant-message-be-delivered-if-the-recipient-is-not-signed-in-to-skype)